# Solving system of two fractional differential equations using Matlab

Tags: matlab, differential

I would appreciate help with this task:

Solve the following system of fractional differential equations:

$$
\begin{cases}A_{1} \cdot D^{2}_{t}y(t)+A_{2} \cdot D^{1}_{t}y(t)+A_{3} \cdot y(t) = 1 \\ B_{1} \cdot D^{2}_{t}y(t)+B_{2} \cdot D^{1}_{t}y(t)+B_{3} \cdot y(t) + B_{4} \cdot D^{v}_{t}y(t) = B_{5} + B_{6} \cdot \frac{t^{-v}}{\Gamma(-v+1)}
 \end{cases}
$$
where
$
A_{1},A_{2},A_{3},B_{1},B_{2},B_{3},B_{4},B_{5},B_{6}
$
are known real numbers

and
$
v
$
is known real **positive** number
$
(v>0)
$

(actually, only the second equation is fractional)

We also know that $y(0)=0$

I want to write a program in Matlab which will find the $y(t)$ , given $A_{1},A_{2},A_{3},B_{1},B_{2},B_{3},B_{4},B_{5},B_{6}$ and $v$

It is okay to use external scripts.

**Update**: Thank you for your comments. I have edited the formatting according to them.

Yes, a numerical solution would be good enough.
Yes, I have found scripts for Matlab to solve fractional differential equations:

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/66603-solving-multiterm-fractional-differential-equations-fde

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32918-predictor-corrector-pece-method-for-fractional-differential-equations

However, they need the set of initial conditions, which are not given in this task.

$D^{\alpha}_{x}$ is a fractional differintegral. For $\alpha > 0$ it is a fractional derivative: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalDerivative.html

**Update 2:** I've replaced $-v$ with $v$ and corrected $\gamma$ to $\Gamma$

**Update 3:** Now the task is easier. We know that $y(0)=0$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please don't use `$$…$$` all the time. Using `$…$` is often enough

Comment: If you don't give your definition of operators $D_t^1$ and  $D_t^2$, you will not have many answers... Is it through an integral ?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have updated my question.

Comment: You can't solve any differential equation numerically without giving initial/boundary conditions. Since your answer should depend on arbitrary constants, it's not possible to get a solution without determining them first. However, in your case, with a fractional derivative I'm not sure how many conditions do we need. I'm not very familiar with the theory

Comment: If $v<0$ why do you write $D^{-v}_t$, isn't it a little confusing? Wouldn't it make sense to define a positive parameter $u=-v$ instead?

Comment: Also, what is $\gamma$ in your case? I would think it's the lower incomplete gamma function, but then it should have two arguments

Comment: By arbitrary constants do you mean A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,B3,B4,B5,B6 and v? If so, they are given, known when solving the system (they will be the arguments of the program).

Comment: Ok, I've changed it from -v to v. Now v is a positive number.
Thank you, $\gamma$ was my mistake in formatting. I've corrected it.

Comment: No, I mean arbitrary constants, which depend on the initial or boundary conditions. For 1 order ODE we have 1 constant, for 2 order 2 constants and so on. Usually, ODE+conditions is the problem set up, which is why we have IVP, BVP etc. However, with fractional derivative, I'm not sure what's the correct set up.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Now I understand. I've found that with fractional derivative we need $m$ constants, where $m$ is the smallest integer greater than the highest order (the highest order in the case of the second equation would be v or 2, depending on v). Here is the source of that information: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/66603-solving-multiterm-fractional-differential-equations-fde ; but there is probably a little mistake and it should state "the smallest integer greater or equal" (assuming from the code, lines 126-130, especially: m_Q = ceil(al_Q) ;").

Comment: I've updated my question. Now it is easier to solve - we know that $y(0)=0$. With only one equation we would need to also know $y'(0)$, but maybe it is enough if we have 2 equations?